# Perfect regex for extracting url with re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I was googling regular expressions for extracting url, but they don't work in one example or python interpreter simply hangs.

The url was 'http://www.computerworld.ru/articles/Naslednik-Hadoop-uskoryaet-evolyutsiyu-analiza-dannyh'

Comment: @yole `((https?:\/\/)?(([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/)?)`, some regular expressions from here https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: OP: Please show us *exactly* what happens when you try to match with that regex.  "don't work" is not much to go on.

Comment: How about this one? `_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS` :)

Comment: @Kevin return list with empty string.

Comment: @ForceBru `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 376-377: truncated \xXX escape`

Comment: @user2558053: Both the `http://` part and the rest of the URL are optional.  Thus, your regex is matching the empty string.  See [this page](https://regex101.com/r/hG6fD0/1) for a detailed breakdown of how the regex is interpreted by Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex for url in python with re.findall :

```
http[s]?:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

if you need capturing group :

```
(http[s]?:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)


http matches the characters http literally (case sensitive)
[s]? match a single character present in the list
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
s the literal character s (case sensitive)
: matches the character : literally
\/ matches the character / literally
\/ matches the character / literally
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
[a-zA-Z] match a single character present in the list below
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative: [0-9]
[0-9] match a single character present in the list below
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
3rd Alternative: [$-_@.&+]
[$-_@.&+] match a single character present in the list below
$-_ a single character in the range between $ and _
@.&+ a single character in the list @.&+ literally (case sensitive)
4th Alternative: [!*\(\),]
[!*\(\),] match a single character present in the list below
!* a single character in the list !* literally
\( matches the character ( literally
\) matches the character ) literally
, the literal character ,
5th Alternative: (?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])
(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]) Non-capturing group
% matches the character % literally
[0-9a-fA-F] match a single character present in the list below
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
a-f a single character in the range between a and f (case sensitive)
A-F a single character in the range between A and F (case sensitive)
[0-9a-fA-F] match a single character present in the list below
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
a-f a single character in the range between a and f (case sensitive)
A-F a single character in the range between A and F (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding, but now I've spotted a probable bug.  You didn't mean to take the range from `$` to `_` in your regex, did you?  Presumably you just wanted to match any of `$`, `-`, and `_`.  Unfortunately, this totally breaks the percent encoding logic by matching the `%` symbol.